# how to hide Wordpress debug.log from bots using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I hide Wordpress debug.log from search bots using .htaccess?

i.e: `/wp-content/debug.log`

Thanks.

Comment: If only restrict from search engines onnly nedd to disallow it in `robots.txt`. But this file shouldn't download by all, so you can protect it by auth: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer from another site which Wordfence had hidden for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp\-content/+debug\.log$
        RewriteRule .* - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <Files "debug.log">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the point of `/?` in the `RewriteCond` line? If we expect the server to not trim `/` characters before doing the match, it should be `/*`, to prevent access to `example.com///wp-content...` etc. If we expect the server to trim them, `/?` is not needed.
I'm also not sure how much adding [NC] to the `RewriteRule` line helps, if the `RewriteCond` is case sensitive. Again, if we expect the server to be in case insensitive mode, than `RewriteCond` should have the `[NC]` flag. If we expect `example.com/wp-content/DEBUG.log` to give a 404, than `[NC]` is not needed on the `RewriteRule` line.